# How to ASP Button onClick= "js variable"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ButtonRadioValue').click(function () {
            var selValue = $('input[name=radio]:checked').val();
        });
    });
```

**Radio**

```
<div id="radio" align="center">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" value="BtnNextCaseClick" name="radio" checked="checked"/><label for="radio1" style="width: 109px; margin-right:-.9em">Next</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" value="CloseCase" name="radio" /><label for="radio2" style="margin-right:-.9em">Close Case</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" value="CloseWeb" name="radio" /><label for="radio3" style="width: 109px">Close Web</label>
</div>
```

So, below that radio I have a button, and I want it to execute different code behind according to radio selection. That value is stored in `selValue`. So how can I tell `onclick` event to run what's inside of `selValue`

**Button**

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonRadioValue" CssClass="customButton" runat="server" onclick=" js variable here" Text="Aceptar" style="width: 111px; height: 30px"/>
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Since there was no real need for client-side procedure. I did it from Server side with `this.radio1.Checked == true`

Comment: Are you wanting to "click" the button that is referenced (by name) in the value of the selected radio button?

Comment: radio1-radio2-radio3. and below them an "OK" button. When user clicks OK, I want to fire some code behind. And there are 3 chances of different code behind blocks. What one is fired depends on the radio selection by user. What's inside of selValue should be the VALUE of those 3 radios.

Comment: If you're purely after the selected radio, why don't you make the radio controls `runat="server"` and then you can see what is selected on the post-back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: It appears I have misunderstood what is required, so I will leave my original below

If you want to know which radio button was selected on the post-back, then either make the radio's server-side controls (either by converting into `<asp:RadioButton>` or simply adding `runat="server"` to them.  Then you can test for `radio1.Checked`, etc.

Otherwise you can check the form data using `Request.Form("radio1")`.  If result is `Nothing` (VB.Net) or `null` (C#) then the radio was not selected.  If there is a value there, you know the radio is selected.

---

**Original / incorrect assumption**

Unless I've misunderstood the issue, you don't need to have a special attribute in the `<asp:Button>` as you can do this just in the jQuery you've already written.

Add the following after your `var selValue...`

```
$("#" + selValue).trigger("click");
```

To produce...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ButtonRadioValue').click(function () {
        var selValue = $('input[name=radio]:checked').val();
        $("#" + selValue).trigger("click");
    });
});
```

One thing to note is that if the control is within Master Page, Placeholder, etc, then the button will need the full ClientID, otherwise the jQuery will not find it

---

As a side note, the `OnClick` attribute of the `<asp:Button>` is used to wire-up the event handler for the click on a post-back to the server.  If you want to run javascript then you want to use the `OnClientClick` attribute, which will produce an `onclick` attribute in the rendered HTML

Comment: Not following completely. This would eliminate my aspbutton?

Comment: @Daniel - apologies, I misunderstood what you were trying to do, I have updated my answer to hopefully be more what you're after - if not, then I simply don't understand your question

Comment: Thank you very much! Values at server-side is what I needed, I mixed it up a little bit with the js. But now it's done. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, good, glad I finally figured out what you needed! Good luck with the rest of your project @Daniel :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for `eval()`.

```
var selValue = $('input[name=radio]:checked').val();
eval(selValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Click is a server event. If you want JS code to execute use `onclientclick`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `OnClientClick` event in order to call client function

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.80).aspx

Server Side : OnClick

Client Side : OnClientClick